# Find and replace JSON objects?

Tags: json, replace

I have a JSON file with a lot of unneeded data and I wish to get rid of most of it.
It a huge file so I need to make an operation that will do that.

I tried Regex but most of the apps I tried seems to stuck in the middle of the process.

What I need is simply find objects by their key and delete them from the file.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not sure what a "JSON Object" is (there really is no such thing).  Sounds like you have a text file in JSON format and you want to filter out various properties from an array of serialized objects.  Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is too large to be read into memory, you might want to use something like [yajl](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/), which provides an event-driven, SAX-like interface. This allows you to make changes to the JSON as you read it (and, I suppose, write it to another file).